# Using Django Framework to compare User form answer as an input and comparing it with a evaluation for a math expression using eval

Tags: python, django

I am having problem coding and figuring out how to compare a value as an answer from the user input of a form  and using that input to compare it with eval(puzzle) which puzzle is  a simple expression like 2+2

Here is some code.

Url: is fine.

Views:

def play(request):

```
if request.user.is_authenticated():
    number_of_records = Puzzles.objects.count()
    random_index = int(random.random()*number_of_records)+1
    rand_puzz = Puzzles.objects.get(id = random_index).puzzle
    solution = eval(rand_puzz)
    if solution = request.GET['a']:
       message = "correct"
       return render(request, 'play.html', {'rand_puzz': rand_puzz, 'message':message})
    else: 
       message = "incorrect"
    return render(request, 'play.html', {'rand_puzz': rand_puzz, message':message})
else:
    return render_to_response('home.html')
```

HTML:

```
    <form action= '/play/' method ="GET">
        <table style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; width:auto;">
<table style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; width:auto; border:solid 1px">
<tr><td><label for="username">Question:</label></td>
<td>{{rand_puzz}}</td></tr>
    <td><input type="number" name="a" value="a" id="a"></td></tr>
    <td>{{solution}}</td></tr> 
     <td> Your answer is:{{message}}</td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" value="submit"/></td></tr>
</table>
        </table>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: Your webapp is open to arbitrary code execution. Don't abuse `eval`.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if it gonna solve your problem but replace

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

rand_puzz = Puzzles.objects.get(id = random_index).puzzle
by
rand_puzz = get_object_or_404(Puzzles,id = random_index)
```

Comment: what does this do ? my rand function works without problems. Its the .GET['a'] that causes issues, There is another problem that I think is a possibility. But first I someone to confirm what I am doing is on the right track

Comment: Puzzles is your model i hope , so you should get Puzzles objects first, it's with this object attribute(rand_puzz.attribute) you can make the time or multiplication with puzzle and (.) is not the time sign.

Comment: I see what you mean. The model is fine, for example when I output to the play page it will be like question : 2+2.. that string that is "2+2" is evaluated eval(rand_puzz) = 4

Comment: then from an input form which is the users answer will compare these  and see if they are equal or not. The problem is that I found is whenever enter a value and submit it is always false. Hence the get function value is getting some garbage value . I suspect From looking at the code I noticed that there is another submit button in another html that also is an action to the play page.


here is the html a input code which is a submit button which takes the users to the play page

Comment: Some code from that loggin.html 
There is a button on this paged called "PLAY NOW" which is a submit button.

here is the html a input code which is a submit button which takes the users to the play page

<form action="/mathgame3/play/" method="get" style="float:left"><input type="submit" id="play" name="play" style="font-size:20pt" value="Play now!"/></form>

does having two submit buttons with the same action mess with the .GET function?

Comment: I removed the form input button submit and only have one and i am a still getting a value from the get function that is not right.

Comment: I solved the problem to compare, however now after running it again without changing anything I get this error


MultiValueDictKeyError at /mathgame3/play/
"Key 'a' not found in <QueryDict